# Output of IIR filter not matching the frequency response - Proximity to fs/4

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter, frequency-response, digital-filters, octave

After not having dealt with digital filters for a long time, I have now been playing around with filter design in octave and I am observing a behavior which I do not understand.

After designing a low-pass Chebychev filter with `cheby1(1,3,0.4)` and plot its frequency response, it can be seen that the -3dB point is exactly at the specified cutoff frequency.

However, when I test the filter with an input wave `x=cos(2*pi*cutoff*t)`, using the filter function `y=filter(b,a,x)`, the amplitude of the output signal can get significantly lower than the expected $0.707$, $0.63$ for this example in particular.

It seems that the output of the filter better approximates the plotted frequency response for cutoff frequencies either close to Nyquist frequency, or close to $0$, but as it gets closer to the middle point between these two, the output steps away from the expected attenuation.

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [octave documentation on cheby1.m](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/cheby1.html) you can see that the cut-off frequency in radians is given by `pi*Wc`, where `Wc` is the cut-off frequency input argument of cheby1.m. So for a function call `[b,a] = cheby1(n,Rp,Wc)`, you should test the filter's gain at the cut-off frequency with an input sequence `cos(Wc*pi*n)`. Furthermore, choose a sufficiently long input signal so that you can observe the filter's steady-state behavior.

Apart from that it's a matter of sampling the time domain function. Note that the samples will generally not occur at the maxima of the sinusoid. I.e., the maximum magnitude of the output signal

$$y[n]=|H(\omega_c)|\cos(n\omega_c+\phi(\omega_c))$$

will not necessarily attain its theoretical maximum value $|H(\omega_c)|$.

Comment: You are right. It had simply to do with the sampling of the time domain function. I tried looping ϕ from 0 to pi, and plotting ϕ against the amplitude of the output of the filter, and indeed the resulting amplitude varies and has a maximum of 0.707. Thanks.